Button Not Showing in Android
Definitely a newbie here.  Using Google Sites and don't have access to Android to test.  I've created a button to copy input text to clipboard.  This works on iOS, Mac, PC but the button doesn't appear on an Android device.  Not sure what I'm missing to make it work on all platforms.
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    <input type="text" id="emailstr" name="w3review" style="color:white;border:none" value=
EMAILSTRING></p>
`your text`<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">COPY</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("emailstr");
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>


Why are you closing the <input> tag with a </p> tag? Your provided code is not valid html!
